# ReactJS - setState fails to update property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a property `name` in a React component. Using `setState` I am trying to modify this property. But assigning a new value to this property inside `setState` has no effect. Please find below my sample code.

```
export const Test = ({
  name,
  changeState = function (newName) {
    this.setState({name: newName}, () => console.log('Name after setState # ' + name)); //prints old value
    console.log(name); // Doesn't reflect changes. Prints old name
  }
 }) => 
(
    <div>Some data</div>
)
```

User action will trigger a call to `changeState(newName)`. I am calling `setState` inside `changeState` function.
After calling `setState` if I print the `name` variable to console it still holds old value. 
How can I make setState assign a new value to `name`?

I am aware that `setState` is asynchronous and update to property may reflect after a delay. But in case of example code above `name` variable is never updated even after a delay.
I have implemented `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method and it gets called but it always receives old `name`. So I don't think the issue is related to `setState` being asynchronous.

I have created an example app to demonstrate the issue I am facing. The example app runs fine locally and I can reproduce the issue. But I am not being able to get the same example app code working in `codepen`. it's giving me some '`unexpected token`' errors. But I hope looking at the code will help understand my issue better. The code is based on existing application structure.

[Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxGgBK).

In the code I have a `Parent` and two children `Child1` and `Child2`. In `Parent` I have a function `changeState` defined which I am passing to `Child1` as property. And to `Child2` I am passing a '`name`' property from `Parent`.
Clicking on '`Change Name`' button in `Child1` triggers a call to `changeState` function of `Parent`. Initial value of `name` in Parent is '`Robert`'. `changeState` is invoked from `Child1` with new name value of '`Tom`'. 
But in `changeState` function assigning new value to '`name`' using `setState` has no effect. I am calling a function to print the 'name' after `setState` has completed but it prints old name value and NOT the new one assigned in `setState`.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using state whilst also using stateless components?

Comment: Your `Test` component is stateless. You can't call `this.setState` because component is stateless. There is no instance to set state on.

Comment: Additionally to what @YuryTarabanko said `setState()` is asynchronous. That means after calling it the change will not immediately be visible in the current state. React may batch multiple calls to `setState`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko is totally right. If you want to manage state you should use a class component.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko is correct. What does `this` even mean in `changeState` function?

Answer (score 0):

You are using stateless component, there's for, there is no state so the setState function doesn't affect anything.

there are 2 options to deal with it:

1. the easiest one, but most likely not the best option, just change your component to regular component:

   `export class Test1 extends React.componnent {
   ...
   (the rest of your component)
   }`
2. the second option (usually a better one in my option) is instead of changing the state for the component, get an event from the parent component, and call the event where you wanted to call the setState, the event would contain an updating the value as requested, and the child component would receive it as prop, and your component wouldn't have to change to Container (a component with state)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. But I am confused about the second approach you are suggesting. Can you please elaborate. I am still learning react and it's only my second week into it.